# Why can't I call the UseInMemoryDatabase method on DbContextOptionsBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First off, I can't use SQL Lite. Secondly the code below is giving me:

> Error CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseInMemoryDatabase' and no extension method 'UseInMemoryDatabase' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The code:

```
 var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProductContext>()
                     .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                     .Options;
 var context = new ProductContext(options);
```

Context

```
using Memory.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Memory.Data
{
    public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProductContext(DbContextOptions<ProductContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My project CSPROJ file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The exact problem is that the method is just not available. I don't seem to understand why. I require enlightenment on this issue.

Answer (score 329, accepted):

According to [EF Core: Testing with InMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) reference, you need to add the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory) package to use `UseInMemoryDatabase()` extension method with `DbContextOptionsBuilder`.

From Visual Studio's Package Manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
```

Or use the cli command:

```
dotnet add package  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
```

Afterwards, you can follow example given in "Writing tests" section like this:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProductContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "database_name").Options;

using (var context = new ProductContext(options))
{
    // add service here
}
```

Answer (score 15):

### Visual Studio 2019: Via the console...

**Tools**(menu) -> **NuGet Package Manager** -> **Package Manager Console** then type `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory`
[image]

### Or by using the Package Manager...

**Tools**(menu) -> **NuGet Package Manager** -> **Manage NuGet Packages for solution** -> NuGet (tab that opened up) -> search for "inmemory" -> Select Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory -> Check the box Project -> **Install**(button)
[image]

### Visual Studio CODE: Via the Terminal...

On the bottom of the screen, select **Terminal**(tab) then type `dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory`

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You need it to use UseInMemoryDatabase

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="3.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 12):

In Mac, open terminal in project directory or In **Visual Studio** Right click on project -> **Tools** -> **Open in Terminal**.

In the terminal install package by following command->

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your ***NuGet Package Manager => Manage Packages for Solution***, check all this packages, whether got **installed** in your solution or not, as below:

1. **EntityFrameworkCore**
2. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**
3. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory**
4. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational**
5. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core**
6. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer**
7. **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools**

I solved the same issues after check all the above packages been installed.

Comment: I don't think we need all of these for the same project. Just Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory is good enough.